# How does Avast Web reputation modifies the links in Google with IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm wondering how does Avast Web reputation modifies the links in Google with Internet Explorer (displaying little bars to show the trust you can put on websites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a [Browser Helper Object (BHO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object). A BHO can access the document of any loaded web page and manipulate the contents.